# Android Remote Debugging not working on Windows 7

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am using the following tutorial to remote debug web pages on android chrome browser.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/mobile/

For Galaxy Nexus I have installed,

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW

When I connect my mobile device on Windows 7 via USB cable and then navigate to,
chrome://inspect/#devices

No device is shown

Answer (score 6):

do you have android ADB in your system? if not install it.
if you have ADB, then in command prompt run `adb devices` and make sure that your device is listed. if its not listed u have to install the device dirver. Also enable usb debugging on your device.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question, but I thought I would post my resolution - I had to enable Developer mode on my Galaxy Note tablet.

Open Settings, then go to About Device (where you see Kernel, Android-version etc) then tap your Build number 7 times.

Then check USB debugging under the now displayed Developer options menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I thought I would also post my solution:

- Update your Chrome on your phone and on your PC.
- Even if it says you have the latest driver for your device inside Device Manager, you may need an alternative.  I went here and got the latest for my Samsung: [Latest USB Drivers](http://trueandroid.com/download-latest-usb-driver-for-android-phonestablets-complete-list-alternatives/)